# How to do social auth with a decoupled backend and frontend (Passport / Express / React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to use passportJS / Express backend, and a react JS frontend, for social auth.  However, I am not certain about how to go about doing so.

I have did some reading and implemented social auth, which returns a JWT token signed by the express app when logged in with Google Auth.  This allows me to access protected endpoints at the backend using the `Authorization` header.

However, how does one trigger this via React, especially since a call to Google should be made directly via the frontend (and hence backend does not do the authentication trigger using Passport JS)?  Specifically, how should this flow look like when both backend and frontend are decoupled?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, lol shortly after posting, I just found this:
https://medium.com/@alexanderleon/implement-social-authentication-with-react-restful-api-9b44f4714fa

The skinny:

- auth client-side via Google
- use Google's token and send over to Express server; verify that tokens are authed and match
- If both match, issue a JWT token to be used in for Express JS API calls.  This should be stored in localStorage.

Comment: storing access token in local storage is considered a bad practice and cause a security vulnerability. consider storing the token in memory or in sessions.