# Authorisation token: OAuth on Django back end, with front end call to 3rd party API. Is this a bad idea?

Tags: python, jquery, django, oauth-2.0

I am learning Django and have an idea for an app that would access data on the Microsoft Graph API for users of their outlook service.

It seems the cleanest way of doing this is by using a package like django-all-auth to handle obtaining and storing the authorisation token in the backend. There’s also an example on the Graph API website using python-social-auth.

However, I’ve been informed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044532/populate-web-page-using-api-result-directly-from-api-server) that I can use a library like jQuery to make the API call directly, meaning the JSON data returned from the 3rd party API could bypass my server and go directly to the user’s browser.

With a 3rd party API requiring authorisation I’d need to get the auth token from my django back end to the front end so that it could be used in the Ajax request.

I appreciate that it would be an option to use the implicit or PKCE flows in the browser.

However, as an alternative I’d had the idea that I could use the server side OAuth flow to store the access token and refresh token in the back end and then send the auth access token from django back end to the user’s browser to be securely stored and used from there.

The benefit of this, as I see it, is that if the user’s access token expired you could make a call to the back end to use the refresh token in order to provide a new auth token, thus requiring the user to log in fewer times.

I also don’t see how this can be any less safe than the implicit flow, although me not seeing it doesn’t mean it doesn’t exist!

I know I’d have to use SSL to avoid any malicious actor snooping on the token. I’d also need to account for CSRF and XSS vulnerabilities, but thankfully django comes with solutions to both.

Would this method be a bad idea and considered bad practice?

My rationale for considering this is that it would reduce greatly the overhead of my server if I could cut out the intermediate step of rendering the JSON response in the page template before it’s sent to the user’s browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I’m describing is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180599/how-to-do-social-auth-with-a-decoupled-backend-and-frontend-passport-express), albeit with different frameworks.

If anyone else reads this and thinks of a problem with what I’m proposing please let me know.